# Fail2ban maxretry meaning

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

I'm reading the following page to set up fail2ban on my Ubuntu server:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fail2ban

In the "Configuration" section, it shows the following settings:

```
[DEFAULT]
# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
bantime  = 3600
maxretry = 3
```

As you can see this contains a `maxretry` setting.  Then, further down in the "Jail Configuration" section, it shows this code:

```
[ssh]

enabled = true
port    = ssh
filter  = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
```

As you can see this also contains a `maxretry` setting. What is the difference between these two settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [onilne  manual page](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Configuration), `[DEFAULT]` directives are effective, unless overiden by specific jail configuration items.

In other words, `maxretry` is redundant in that example, as it is being set by the `[DEFAULTS]` section anyway.

One different scenario would be if you had a different setting for the `[ssh]` jail.

Answer (score 3):

The first block [DEFAULT] sets default values for jails you have not defined other values.